# how to convert datamatrix code from hubarcode to PILimage

Tags: python, barcode

I'm trying to encode a string into a DataMatrix using the [hubarcode package](https://github.com/hudora/huBarcode). I would like to convert the `en` object to a PIL image so that I can use it further downstream.

If I read [this function](https://github.com/hudora/huBarcode/blob/master/hubarcode/datamatrix/renderer.py#L65) correctly, `get_pilimage()` is defined and I figured `en.get_pilimage()` should work, but of course doesn't. When I examine `dir(en)`, `get_pilimage` is not defined (only `get_imagedata` and `get_ascii`). Is this because `get_pilimage` is not defined in [`__init__.py` for `DataMatrixRenderer`](https://github.com/hudora/huBarcode/blob/e89cc42a4325aaab20297fecd33a785061633bed/hubarcode/datamatrix/__init__.py)?

This is the code I use

```
# pip install huBarcode
from hubarcode.datamatrix import DataMatrixEncoder
en = DataMatrixEncoder("M103")
en.get_imagedata() # result below
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00F\x00\x00\x00F\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00TE\xbdX\x00\x00\x00\x9aIDATx\x9c\xed\x98\xc1\n\xc00\x08Cu\xf4\xff\x7f\xb9\xbbM\x16t\xb3\xc3CV\xcc\xc9ayh\x10i\xa7S*t\x94P\x1a\xd3\x98O\x1a\x16\xaa\x88\xc8\\\x89\xca\xab\xd9\x12\xa3\xe6\x95^Q\xe8d\xe83WS\\\x98\x01\xdf\x9e\xa7\x90\xed)^\x13Zl\xfe=\x9b\xddS\x9c\x16Z\x0c\x82\xe5\x01Qy5[b\xdcE\xe1me\xb9G\x96\xad\xacfK\xcc\xcb\x14\x87\xea]\x9cV|\xa3\xc0\x83W\xc2;\xc7\xd5\x14\x17\xc6\xb5\x18\x94x\x00r5\xc5\x85\xc9,\x8a\x84\xf7\\Mqa\xb4\xffQ4\xe6\xf7\x98\x13\xd1\xa9\x1f\x8e\x11\x9b\xc5\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'

en.get_pilimage() # doesn't work, but I imagine result would be an image
```

Alternatively, is there another way of converting the result of `en.get_imagedata()` to png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up grabbing the raw image string, converting it to `BytesIO` object and passing the stream to `PIL.Image`.

```
import io
import PIL
from hubarcode.datamatrix import DataMatrixEncoder

dm = DataMatrixEncoder("M103")
dm_in_bytes = io.BytesIO(dm.get_imagedata())
img = PIL.Image.open(dm_in_bytes)

img.show()
```

[image: datamatrix code from hubarcode python]